# Typescript Type ‘string’ is not assignable to type when returning value indirectly

Tags: typescript

I am trying to have a type with hardcoded values.

```
interface TheThing {
  foo: 'start'
}

const bar =(): TheThing => {
  return {
    foo: 'start'
  }
}

const foo = (): TheThing => {
  const result = {
    foo: 'start'
  }
  return result // Does not work
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrABAFQBa11AOYYDeoGGiA9lQFwYDkAztMvNA6AL6i8ipVILDACM2GALwAKAJT1c%20HEUkA%20UuQzxY0AK7xI6kBQrU6jFmw4aeIG3wwCh0SjUkZZ8vAUjEJaskYOgsJaTDoANs4ShsYuZsys7JyBNhRauvqasGGR3KBAA)

But it fails with:

```
Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TheThing'.
  Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"start"
```

Why does the second one not work without directly using type annotation on `result`?

Comment: You're missing a dash...?

Comment: Duh.. ok I was trying to make a simple example of my code but evidently that's not it :). deleting and will try to make working one. face palm

Comment: Does a type annotation work? `const result: TheThing = { … }` -- you need an explicit annotation since TS infers the broadest type for the literal--string

Comment: It does!. Why though? I would think TS smart enough to make it work

Comment: TypeScript cannot infer anything about the object literal in relation to the types you defined (if you had two interfaces `TheThing` and `TheThing1` declared exactly the same--which one would it choose?). So it just assumes the broadest type `string` for the literal string which isn't assignable as reported. You need to tell TS explicitly via an annotation the narrower type you assert the object literal is.

Comment: I guess I don't follow. If my result looks exactly like the expected return value of the function why complain? I already told TS what type to expect in return.

Comment: You've told it what to return, yes. But, TS infers that `result` has type `{ foo: string }`, and `string` is not compatible with the stricter type `'start'` in `TheThing`. And the reason why TS infers `{ foo: string }` is because it's an object literal with no extra context. TS has no way of knowing how `TheThing` relates with `result` unless you tell it with an annotation

Comment: For all TS knows, `result` could be of type `TheOtherThing` defined as `interface TheOtherThing { foo: 'start' | 'another!' }` so TS doesn't make any assumptions.

Comment: Contextual typing doesn't propagate too far.  If you are returning a freshly created object literal `return {...}`, the desired return type will be used as context for that object literal.  But if you put the object literal into a new unannotated variable and return that,  `const foo = {...}; return foo;`, there's no return-type context for the variable `foo`, which gets inferred according to heuristics (string literals tend to be widened to `string`).  The only way the compiler could figure this out is if contextual typing back-propagated through multiple statements which isn't what it does.